# How to send "HTML SELECT VALUE" to another webpage with ajax without refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Where is a problem ? . I want to send selected value to another webpage without refresh page. Than i try using ajax.
Here is all script (only one file) i want to send value 0,2,4 like parameter "t" to another web page. But function $.ajax didn't work. but after part with alert yes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>jQuery With Example</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      $('.btnClick').click(function () {
         $.ajax({
            url:'http://ip adress:84/?t='+ $('.sendnumber').val(), //the page for example http://192.168.100.100:84/?t=2 
            type: 'POST',
             });

        alert('Value = ' + $('.sendnumber').val());
        alert('Text = ' + $('.sendnumber option:selected').text());
      });
    })
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <select class="sendnumber">
      <option value="0">24</option>
      <option value="2">25</option>
      <option value="4">26</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="button" class="btnClick" value="Click" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me.
Thanks Hunt3r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just noticed that your jquery selector is wrong for the option value, use this instead:

```
$('.sendnumber option:selected').val()
```

Comment: only AJAX didnt POST the request. both alerts is showing on  :-(

Comment: Check this, it alerts the correct values and tries to do the ajax request as expected:  https://jsfiddle.net/o7auqjxn/

Comment: Alerts is ok value is ok. but ajax i mean dindt send request

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the HTML it's hard to say, but remember that posting to a page on a different domain will require the appropriate CORS setting up, as this is a cross origin security setting

Comment: cross security isnt problem . i have 2 servers in one local subnet. When i send "by hand" in IE browser http://xxxxx.xxx/?value=2 it is OK